# How to calculate the runtime complexity of triangular number generation

Tags: c++, big-o

I understand that the below code snippet is used to print triangular numbers which are less than n. How do we determine the runtime complexity (big O ) of it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 100;
    int i = 1;
    while (sum <= n) {
       sum = sum + i;
       cout << sum << endl;
       i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your complexity is currently `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the complexity to be along the lines of `sqrt(n)`.

Essentially, we're adding numbers till we reach the sum n.
i.e., 
`(1)+(2)+.....(k) <= n`
Which leads to the following inequality: `(k)*(k+1)/2 <=n`

You can solve it, to get k in terms of n, where `k` represents the number of iterarions your program has to run for a given `n`.

For simplifications, just compare higher order terms on both sides, which leads to:
`k^2 = n`
Hence, 
Complexity is **O(sqrt(n))**

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code is following the pattern

sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + m

which has the formula of

sum = m(m+1)/2

sum = (m^2+m)/2

n = (m^2+m)/2

considering the higher order on both sides

n = m^2

sqrt(n) = m

where n is the number of elements in the sequence

Therefore the complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: It has to be smaller than `O(n)`

Comment: Sum is not following the sequence of n*(n+1)/2. Rather it is bound by n.